# Does jar manifest support `Class-Path`? Why use spring-boot-loader instead?

Tags: spring-boot, manifest, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I know that spring boot packages an executable jar with `spring-boot-loader` and loads other jars from `BOOT-INF/lib` as described in [this post](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html), using a class named `JarLauncher`.

After reading [this post](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html), I was thinking that `Class-Path` in manifest can do this, too.

So why does spring boot do so many works to load jars from a customed `BOOT-INF/lib`, rather than just write simply in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Class-Path: BOOT-INF/lib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Class-Path` manifest approach does not support loading classes from jar files nested within a jar. From the Oracle documentation that you've linked to in your question:

> The Class-Path header points to classes or JAR files on the local network, not JAR files within the JAR file or classes accessible over Internet protocols. To load classes in JAR files within a JAR file into the class path, you must write custom code to load those classes. For example, if MyJar.jar contains another JAR file called MyUtils.jar, you cannot use the Class-Path header in MyJar.jar's manifest to load classes in MyUtils.jar into the class path.

Spring Boot's `JarLauncher` and the other classes in `spring-boot-loader` are the custom code that allow classes to be loaded from jars nested within a jar.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the meaning of the Oracle doc I post...When seeing `Java does not provide any standard way to load nested jar files` from spring boot doc, I feel confused. Thanks to point out the mistake and everything clears now :D